# Confused about using trait with lifetime as generic parameter constraint

Tags: rust

I am trying to make some kind of decoder, that will be able to deserialize entries without actually copying memory, just by mapping values to some memory regions. That is what I currently managed to do (simplified for testcase):

```
#![allow(unstable)]

trait CastAbility: Sized { }
impl CastAbility for u64 { }
impl CastAbility for u32 { }
impl CastAbility for u16 { }
impl CastAbility for u8 { }

trait Cast {
    fn cast<'a>(mem: &'a [u8]) -> Result<&'a Self, String>;
}

impl<T> Cast for T where T: CastAbility {
    fn cast<'a>(mem: &'a [u8]) -> Result<&'a T, String> {
        if mem.len() != std::mem::size_of::<T>() { 
            Err("invalid size".to_string())
        } else {
            Ok(unsafe { std::mem::transmute(mem.as_ptr()) })
        }
    }
}

impl Cast for str {
    fn cast<'a>(mem: &'a [u8]) -> Result<&'a str, String> {
        Ok(unsafe { std::mem::transmute(std::raw::Slice { data: mem.as_ptr(), len: mem.len() }) })
    }
}

trait Read<'a> {
    fn read(mem: &'a [u8]) -> Result<Self, String>;
}

#[derive(Show, PartialEq)]
struct U8AndStr<'a> {
    value_u8: &'a u8,
    value_str: &'a str,
}

impl<'a> Read<'a> for U8AndStr<'a> {
    fn read(mem: &'a [u8]) -> Result<U8AndStr, String> {
        Ok(U8AndStr {
            value_u8: try!(Cast::cast(mem.slice(0, 1))),
            value_str: try!(Cast::cast(mem.slice(1, mem.len()))),
        })
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mem: &[u8] = &[0x01, 0x30, 0x31, 0x32, 0x33, 0x34, 0x35, 0x36, 0x37];
    let value: U8AndStr = Read::read(mem).unwrap();

    println!("value: {:?}", value);
}
```

[playpen](http://is.gd/ITgBDy)

In fact it compiles and even works, but now I cannot understand how to use my *Read* trait as generic parameter. For example, suppose I want to compare a value to a decoded result of some memory area:

```
fn compare_to_smth<'a, T>(value: &'a T) -> bool where T: PartialEq+Read<'a> {
    let mem: &[u8] = &[0x01, 0x30, 0x31, 0x32, 0x33, 0x34, 0x35, 0x36, 0x37];
    let smth_value: T = Read::read(mem).unwrap();
    smth_value == *value
}

fn main() {
    let value = U8AndStr { value_u8: &1, value_str: "01234567" };
    assert!(compare_to_smth(&value));
}
```

It fails with "borrowed value does not live long enough", and I can guess why: because *mem* lifetime is the function body, not *'a*, as I did specify in signature for input parameter. So I tried to use second lifetime paramater as shown:

```
fn compare_to_smth<'a, 'b, T>(value: &'a T) -> bool where T: PartialEq+Read<'b> {
```

But it also didn't work for obvious reason. So I really don't understand how to make *compare_to_smth* work without passing memory chunk from outside. Is there any solution, or I should refactor the code somehow?

Comment: Based on your previous question, you should also state that you cannot move the `'a` from the `Read` trait to the `read` method, which would be my first suggestion.

Comment: But it seems that I cannot move it in this situation because I need to implement trait for U8AndStr<'a>.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately, what you want to do is inexpressible in Rust at the moment.

The signature of `Read` trait that actually would work is as follows (in pseudo-Rust):

```
trait<'r> Read for Self<'r> {
    fn read<'a>(mem: &'a [u8]) -> Result<Self<'a>, String>;  // '
}
```

That is, `Self` must be a higher-kinded type in its lifetime parameter. This requires support for higher-kinded types, which is a very desired feature in the Rust community but which is still yet to be implemented.

The problem with the original signature:

```
trait Read<'a> {
    fn read(mem: &'a [u8]) -> Result<Self, String>;
}
```

is that `'a` is a parameter to the trait. When this trait is used as a trait bound:

```
fn compare_to_smth<'a, T>(value: &T) -> bool where T: PartialEq+Read<'a>
```

it means that *the caller* of this function chooses the actual lifetime parameter. For example, the caller may choose `'static`:

```
fn compare_to_smth<T>(value: &T) -> bool where T: PartialEq+Read<'static>
```

However, the function uses `&[u8]` whose lifetime is not `'static`.

In fact, this concrete example may be not exactly correct due to variance (I imagine it would be sound for this lifetime to be `'static` here, but variance of lifetimes itself is somewhat confusing, so I'm not really sure), but nevertheless the general idea is the same: in order for this to work the `Read::read` method must be polymorphic in the lifetime of its argument and result, but you can't write such signature yet.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! Maybe you can help me to find out the correct way to implement my idea in rust using currently available abstractions?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think its is currently possible. I've also encountered this when I tried to improve the type safety of some of my code (though I needed parameterized associated types, not `Self`). I couldn't found a way around it.

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue might be more in the signature of `compare_to_smth`.

```
fn compare_to_smth<'a, T>(value: &'a T) // this implies a T: 'a bound
                       // because otherwise we would not be able to
                       // have a &'a T (references can't live longer
                       // than the thing they reference)
```

but then inside the function you're doing:

```
let smth_value: T = Read::read(mem).unwrap(); 
                                 // give me something of type T that
                                 // lives less than T
```

I may be wrong, but I don't think this depends on how `Read` is defined and how sophisticated the type system can become in the future, as whatever you write on the right side doesn't change the fact that you're expecting a T on the left side (and T has to outlive `'a`).

A "sufficiently smart compiler" might be able to see that smth_value is actually not living longer than `'a` and that what you're doing is safe, but in general this would be unsafe.
I'm sure that using an unsafe transmute in `compare_to_smth` completely defeats your purpose, but just to demonstrate, this works:

```
fn compare_to_smth<'a, T>(value: &'a T) -> bool
    where T: Read<'a> + PartialEq
{
    let mem: &[u8] = &[0x01, 0x30, 0x31, 0x32, 0x33, 0x34, 0x35, 0x36, 0x37];
    let smth_value = <U8AndStr as Read>::read(mem).unwrap();
    let vl: &U8AndStr = unsafe{ std::mem::transmute(value) };

    smth_value == *vl
}
```